# Find a skew Hilbert-Schmidt operator $S$ such that $a+bS$ is invertible.

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, equipped with a decomposition $H = L \oplus L'$, where $L$ and $L'$ are closed infinite-dimensional subspaces of $H$.

Let $J$ be the operator that acts by $+i$ on $L$ and by $-i$ on $L'$. Define the restricted orthogonal group on $H$ by
\begin{equation}
 \text{O}_{J}(H) = \{ g \in \text{O}(H) \mid [g,J] \text{ is Hilbert-Schmidt} \}.
\end{equation}
Let $g \in \text{O}_{J}(H)$ be arbitrary. Then we can write
\begin{equation}
 g = \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
 \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $a: L \rightarrow L$ and $d: L' \rightarrow L'$ are Fredholm, and $b : L' \rightarrow L$ and $c : L \rightarrow L'$ are Hilbert-Schmidt.

> **Claim**: There exists a skew Hilbert-Schmidt operator $S: L \rightarrow L'$, such that $a + bS$ is invertible.

I don't see how to prove this. I tried writing out
\begin{equation}
 g^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
  a' & b' \\
  c' & d'
 \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
and then working out the product $gg^{-1}$ in components, with the idea of finding an explicit expression for $S$ in terms of the components of $g^{-1}$. One obtains for example the expression
\begin{equation}
 aa' + bc' = \mathbf{1},
\end{equation}
which suggests setting $S = c'$, but I couldn't get this to quite work out. I guess I have to also use the fact that $a$ is Fredholm, i.e. ''invertible modulo a compact operator'', but I also don't quite see how this should work out.